# Implementing Search in my java function

Tags: java

I need a java code that chooses the shortest path between two words with each step only changing one letter. I'd like to implement Depth-First Search; I think that would solve my problem. I was reading about it but I don't know how to implement it. Could anyone help me?

Comment: DFS won't guarantee the shortest path. Do you mean breadth-first search? Also, please provide sample input and expected output if possible.

Comment: I added the expected output. Why is it better to use breadth-first search in my case?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on your specific case yet, but in general, DFS can't find the shortest path between two nodes because it doesn't iterate outward from the start node as BFS does. It just drills all the way down to the bottom of the graph (hence depth-first). If it hits the target node it may have taken non-optimal route to get there. It may be faster than BFS, though, if a non-optimal route is acceptable and depending on the problem constraints. You might need a heuristic for this problem--if you're brute forcing, on quick glance it looks like you have a branching factor of about 25.

Comment: Most importantly, can you make your example [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by eliminating the dictionary and input components that are non-critical? What does your dictionary look like (how many lines, what kind of words, etc)? Can you hard code a relevant subset of it or provide a link to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I overestimated some of the problem constraints in my comment; this is actually a very straightforward [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) problem. [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) is not appropriate because it follows each path all the way to a terminal node before exploring neighbors of nodes close to the root node. This means there is no guarantee of shortest path. On the other hand, BFS explores nearby nodes first and will guarantee a shortest path. This problem illustrates the difference between the two approaches very nicely.

Your current implementation is recursive, which uses the call stack as the DFS data structure. Since stacks are last-in-first-out (LIFO) structures, neighbors of the current node will be quickly buried underneath neighbors of those neighbors which are popped and explored first.

Here's an implementation of your `find` method as BFS using a queue (first-in-first-out or FIFO):

```
def find(start, target, words):
    alpha = [chr(x) for x in range(97, 123)]
    visited = {start: None}
    queue = [start]

    while queue:
        curr = queue.pop(0)

        if curr == target:
            path = []

            while curr:
                path.insert(0, curr)
                curr = visited[curr]

            return path

        letters = list(curr)

        for i, c in enumerate(letters):
            for letter in alpha:
                new_word = "".join(letters[:i]) + letter + "".join(letters[i+1:])

                if new_word in words and new_word not in visited:
                    visited[new_word] = curr
                    queue.append(new_word)


words = set([w.strip() for w in open("dictionary.txt").readlines()])
print(find("lead", "gold", words))
print(find("hide", "seek", words))
```

Output:

```
['lead', 'load', 'goad', 'gold']
['hide', 'bide', 'bids', 'beds', 'bees', 'sees', 'seek']
```

Note that the second path is equally short as your example but uses a different route. You could easily adjust the algorithm to calculate all shortest paths if desired.

In contrast, a simple modification of changing the queue to a stack (one character change: `pop(0) -> pop()` shows us the result of a DFS:

```
['lead', 'leas', 'leys', 'lays', 'laws', 'lawn', 'lain', 'lair', 'wair', 'wait', 'watt', 'wats', 'wars', 'wary', 'wavy', 'wave', 'wane', 'wand', 'wynd', 'wyns', 'wyes', 'woes', 'wows', 'yows', 'yowl', 'yawl', 'yawp', 'yaup', 'yaud', 'yard', 'yarn', 'tarn', 'tart', 'taut', 'taus', 'tavs', 'vavs', 'vans', 'vang', 'yang', 'yank', 'yack', 'yuck', 'yuch', 'yech', 'yeah', 'year', 'wear', 'wean', 'ween', 'weet', 'west', 'wost', 'wort', 'worn', 'sorn', 'sori', 'soli', 'sols', 'soys', 'soya', 'soma', 'some', 'sone', 'song', 'sung', 'suns', 'suss', 'sass', 'sash', 'wash', 'wasp', 'wisp', 'wiss', 'wigs', 'zigs', 'zits', 'ziti', 'titi', 'tipi', 'tips', 'tins', 'tiny', 'tidy', 'tide', 'tire', 'tiro', 'tyro', 'typo', 'type', 'tyne', 'tune', 'tuna', 'tufa', 'tuft', 'toft', 'tofu', 'tolu', 'toll', 'tool', 'toon', 'town', 'towy', 'tory', 'tors', 'tots', 'tote', 'toke', 'take', 'taka', 'taxa', 'taxi', 'tali', 'talk', 'task', 'tusk', 'tush', 'tosh', 'toph', 'soph', 'soth', 'sith', 'site', 'size', 'bize', 'bise', 'bisk', 'birk', 'birr', 'bier', 'beer', 'bees', 'bets', 'beth', 'bath', 'bate', 'bare', 'barm', 'balm', 'bals', 'bams', 'bums', 'bump', 'burp', 'bury', 'busy', 'bust', 'butt', 'bott', 'bota', 'bora', 'mora', 'more', 'move', 'rove', 'roue', 'roux', 'doux', 'dour', 'dorr', 'dorp', 'gorp', 'goop', 'goos', 'gods', 'gids', 'gies', 'gien', 'girn', 'girt', 'gist', 'gast', 'vast', 'vase', 'vale', 'vole', 'volt', 'molt', 'moly', 'mopy', 'mops', 'moss', 'mosk', 'monk', 'mono', 'mozo', 'bozo', 'bolo', 'bold', 'gold']
['hide', 'hive', 'hove', 'howe', 'hows', 'hoys', 'hoya', 'hora', 'horn', 'hern', 'hers', 'hets', 'heth', 'hath', 'hate', 'haze', 'hazy', 'mazy', 'many', 'mans', 'mays', 'mayo', 'mako', 'make', 'mare', 'mart', 'maut', 'maun', 'mawn', 'mown', 'moon', 'moot', 'mott', 'mots', 'moss', 'mosk', 'monk', 'mono', 'mozo', 'bozo', 'boyo', 'toyo', 'toro', 'tory', 'towy', 'cowy', 'cowl', 'cool', 'coos', 'cops', 'cope', 'cote', 'cute', 'cuts', 'cuss', 'cusk', 'cask', 'cast', 'cant', 'cane', 'cave', 'cavy', 'caky', 'laky', 'lakh', 'lash', 'lass', 'laws', 'yaws', 'yawp', 'yaup', 'yaud', 'yard', 'yarn', 'warn', 'wary', 'waly', 'wall', 'wawl', 'pawl', 'pail', 'pair', 'parr', 'pars', 'pats', 'paty', 'pity', 'pith', 'pish', 'piss', 'pips', 'pipe', 'pine', 'pint', 'punt', 'puny', 'pony', 'pons', 'poms', 'pomp', 'poop', 'poor', 'pour', 'pout', 'post', 'pose', 'pore', 'pork', 'pock', 'poco', 'polo', 'poll', 'pull', 'puls', 'pugs', 'pugh', 'vugh', 'vugg', 'mugg', 'migg', 'migs', 'mirs', 'miry', 'airy', 'airt', 'girt', 'giro', 'gyro', 'gyre', 'gybe', 'gibe', 'gibs', 'gins', 'gink', 'gunk', 'guck', 'geck', 'geek', 'seek']
```

As you can see, that wasn't the shortest path at all!

Comment: @Tio No problem. I'd make that a new question since it's a fair step beyond what you already asked, and give it a shot on your own first. Hint: when the conditional `if curr == target:` is true, the loop ends and *a* path is returned. You'll need to modify this to keep searching.

Comment: That's all right, it's not an easy problem at all. I'd work on understanding the code more and trying to explain the expected behavior on your new post, e.g. with detailed input and output examples. Folks might downvote it for "no attempt". I'll take a look when I can.

Answer (score -1):

I think we are in the same class, with the same assignment. Just a heads up, be careful what you post online especially your codes as it could get detected by our lecturer and fail your assignment as it is a violation of academic policy, specifically plagiarism. :)

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer. [Answer or comment: what's the etiquette?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/answer-or-comment-whats-the-etiquette)